# how to make the cursor work and to fill in the list , the values ​in a row of the only parameter of the procedure

Tags: mysql

I have a procedure that uses a cursor.
It looks in a table for an ID and a value.
The procedure works but only with a single value is entered.
I prepared a temporary table and also a variable where I concatenated the values from the temporary table.
How can I make it work by entering the concatenated values?

The table that looks like this:

```
(id_ct, no_ct, no_gr, no_per, zone_ID_zone) values
(1, CT31781, 0101, 1, 888888),
(2, CT31781, 0101, 2, 888888),
(3, CT31781, 0101, 3, 789),
(4, CT31780, 0101, 4, 888888),
(5, CT31780, 0101, 5, 888888),
(6, CT31780, 0101, 6, 788);

CREATE PROCEDURE `find_proo88` (in CTS varchar(255))
    begin
    Declare a int default 0;
    Declare i int default 0;
    DEClare b int default 0;
    declare c decimal  (4.2);
    DECLARE V_LISTA  VARCHAR(65000);
    declare v_user int;
    declare v_status varchar(20);
    declare ok int;

    DECLARE CURS cursor for
            SELECT CT.ID_CT, CT.zone_id_zone
            FROM  CT  
        where CT.NO_CT = CTS ;

        declare continue handler for not found
        begin
        set ok=1;
        end;

    open curs;
    START TRANSACTION;
        bucla :loop
            fetch curs into v_user , v_status;
            if ok=1 then leave bucla;
            end if;
            if v_status = "888888" then
            set a=a+1;
            else set i=i+1;
            end if;
        end loop bucla;
      COMMIT;   
      close curs;

        SET  b = a+i;
        set  c = (b-a)/b*100;
        SELECT  CONCAT_WS(" " , v_lista ,cts,"        Perechi Libere " , a ,  "           Perechi Ocupate ", i ,"        Total Perechi " , b  , "          Full ", CONCAT_WS("", c ," % ")) INTO V_LISTA;
    SELECT V_LISTA as "cutii terminale";


end;
```

Comment: Please add your expected outcome.

Comment: CT31781 , 2 , 1 , 3 , 66,6%
CT31780, 2 , 1 , 3 , 66,6%

the result one below the other in a single list

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with a simple view.
   I didn't use the cursor.

```
create OR REPLACE view find_proo88 as
select id_ct,no_ct as "Numar Cutie Terminala" , no_gr as "Numar Grup", b.bl_name as "Bloc" , b.bl_sc as "Scara", b.bl_et_ct as "Etajul Cutiei Terminale", s.str_name as "Strada", s.str_no as "No",cl.Rank as Rank,
    count(*) Total,
        sum(case when CT.zone_id_zone = '888888' then 1 else 0 end) 'Perechi libere',
        sum(case when CT.zone_id_zone != '888888' then 1 else 0 end) 'Perechi Ocupate',
        CONCAT_WS(" " ,(TRUNCATE(avg((case when CT.zone_id_zone = '888888' then 1 else 0 end)*100),0) ),"%") 'Grup Liber',
        CONCAT_WS(" " ,(TRUNCATE(avg((case when CT.zone_id_zone != '888888' then 1 else 0 end)*100),0) ),"%") 'Grup Ocupat',
        sum(case when CL.Rank = 'Activ' then 1 else 0 end) 'Rank Activ',
        sum(case when CL.Rank != 'Activ' then 1 else 0 end) 'Rank Inactiv',
        CONCAT_WS(" " ,(TRUNCATE(avg((case when Rank = 'Activ' then 1 else 0 end)*100),0) ),"%") 'R Activ',
        CONCAT_WS(" " ,(TRUNCATE(avg((case when Rank != 'Activ' then 1 else 0 end)*100),0) ),"%")  'R Inactiv'
    from ct
join building b on b.id_build=ct.building_Id_build
join street s on s.id_str=b.street_id_str
join client cl on cl.street_id_str = s.id_str
group by no_ct
```